# Liferay + NgCloak

Tags: java, css, liferay, portal, ngcloak

I'm trying to use ngcloak with liferay. I have a very big portal and I'm trying to use ng-cloak but it doesn't work. I read that to use ngcloak is necessary to include angular-csp.css, where could I include it?Inside liferay-portlet.xml?
And I just need to write for exaple:

angular-csp.css

Thank you all

Comment: By "not work", what do you mean?  Any error messages?  What have you tried?

Comment: Not work I mean that I still see angular variables at the page loading 
{{ variable1}} {{variable2}}

Comment: I put ng-cloak inside the div with variables and then I've tryed tu include angular-csp.css in liferay-portlet.xml as I writed on and then I've tryed to insert the rule [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
} 
in an other css